# HTTP Error 406: Not acceptable en Python

Tags: python

Buen día gente, estoy empezando a trabajar con documentos en json en Python y me sale el siguiente error al compilar el código:

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable

**Código:**

```py
# Leer archivo json
# json = JavaScript Object Notation
import urllib.request
import json

respuesta = urllib.request.urlopen('http://globalmentoring.com.mx/api/personas.json')
print(respuesta)
cuerpo_respuesta = respuesta.read()
print(cuerpo_respuesta)
# Procesamos la respuesta json
json_respuesta = json.loads(cuerpo_respuesta.decode("utf-8"))
print(json_respuesta)
# Imprimimos sólo los nombres de las personas
# json se convierte a listas y diccionarios de python
print('Nombres de las personas en el archivo json:')
for persona in json_respuesta['personas']:
    print(persona['nombre'], persona['edad'])
# Accedemos al total de personas de archivo
print(f'Total de personas: {json_respuesta["total"]}')
# Accedemos al mensaje del archivo
print(f'Mensaje: {json_respuesta["mensaje"]}')
```

Agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema, es que algunos servidores necesitan la cabecera [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) y este parece ser uno de ellos.

> Por defecto, los navegadores ya añaden esa cabecera a la petición

Para solucionarlo, puedes preparar la petición usando la clase [Request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) y añadir esa cabecera

Por ejemplo:

```
from urllib.request import Request
from urllib.request import urlopen

import json

request = Request("http://globalmentoring.com.mx/api/personas.json")
# Añadir la cebecera User-Agent a la peticion
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36')
respuesta  = urlopen(request)

cuerpo_respuesta = respuesta.read()
# Procesamos la respuesta json
json_respuesta = json.loads(cuerpo_respuesta.decode("utf-8"))
print(json_respuesta)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió la solución.